# The regular expression does not match

Tags: python, regex, go

I tried to get SQL information from log files using regular expressions

The information I need is the running time of the SQL, the SQL statement, the parameters of the SQL

Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "regexp"
)

func main(){
    file,err:=os.OpenFile("./log.txt",os.O_RDWR,0755)
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    b,err:=ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    str:=string(b)
    r,err:=regexp.Compile(`\[ORM\][\w\W]+?(\d*.\d*ms|\d*.\d*s)\][ -]+\[([\w\W]+?)\]`)

    s:=r.FindAllStringSubmatch(str,-1)
    fmt.Println(s[0][3])
    fmt.Println(s[1][3])
}
```

This is my log sample

> [ORM]2018/08/03 10:23:50  -[Queries/read] - [  OK /    db.Query /   432.4ms] - [SELECT acc.*,gp.group_name,gp.group_id,org.org_name,group_concat(r.role_name) role_name
>               FROM sys_account acc
>               LEFT JOIN sys_org org on org.org_id=acc.org_id
>               LEFT JOIN sys_group gp on gp.group_id=org.group_id
>               LEFT JOIN sys_account_role ar on ar.acct_id=acc.acct_id and ar.is_del=0
>               LEFT JOIN sys_role r on r.role_id=ar.role_id  where 1=1  and acc.acct_type=1  group by acc.acct_id order by acc.create_time  desc  LIMIT 0, 15] - `1` `ASDFASDF`
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) received CLOSE_WAIT from nsqd
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) beginning close
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) readLoop exiting
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) breaking out of writeLoop
>   nsq consumer2: INF   13 [RYOLST_Ch_admin/crm] (192.168.1.233:4150) writeLoop exiting
>   [ORM]2018/08/03 10:23:50  -[Queries/default] - [  OK /    db.Query /     0.6ms] - [select * from sys_group where group_id=? ] - `111` `qwqwqw`

I hope so Print out the

`1` `ASDFASDF`

`111` `qwqwqw`

I'm now left with the last argument that I can't get

These parameters may or may not be multiple、You can also have too many arguments wrapping around the file

I have tried this myself：

```
r,err:=regexp.Compile(`\[ORM\][\w\W]+?(\d*.\d*ms|\d*.\d*s)\][ -]+\[([\w\W]+?)\][ -]*((\W\w*\W{1,2})*)`)
r,err:=regexp.Compile(`\[ORM\][\w\W]+?(\d*.\d*ms|\d*.\d*s)\][ -]+\[([\w\W]+?)\][- ]*([^\n]*)`)
```

Comment: Why the Python and Go tags? Which language are you using? Also, what are some sample inputs and expected outputs? Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: Hello, I have already modified the problem, I use golang now, but regular expressions are the same, python USES more regular expressions

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question. Please take some time to [format it properly](/help/formatting).

Comment: I've described it clearly, and it has nothing to do with the code. Regular expressions are the same in any language. Thank you for your reply. Let me think for myself. It should work out

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please edit it so we can be sure of 1. **the regular expression you are using** 2. **the desired output** 3. **The input**.

Comment: Okay, I'm rearranging the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like this regexp:

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\[ORM\][^-]* -\[[^]]*\] - \[ .* / .* / ([^]]*)] - \[([^]]*)\] - (.*)`)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/MUBzaiyyCWt

This assumes well-formed data, one entry per line. If not you probably won't be able to parse it with a regexp, and even this makes some assumptions about queries not including the strings [] (which you might get away with).

First I'd double check that you absolutely cannot get this data output in the right format in the first place - if you can it'd be far better to get the output you want directly, perhaps even have a separate log, or even better send metrics like this to a time series database for later analysis. Parsing logs for this sort of info isn't great, particularly if done on an ongoing basis.

If you must parse logs, some advice on testing this:

- Use play.golang.org for a quick tests
- Use regexp.MustCompile to check your regexp works
- Create a function to parse the lines
- Write some tests which exercise your function, using lines from the log